# Multiple-value f.strength in single-value context

Tags: go

I have the function `Strength()`:

```
func (g Group) Strength() (Name []Entity, err error)
```

I am trying to call this function and store the values in some variable like below:

```
for _,x := range f.Strength() {
        ...
    }
```

But this is giving error:

> multiple-value f.strength in single-value context

Comment: `range` takes a single value, so you can't use a function that returns multiple values in that spot. You have to call it first and do the `range` on the first return value.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range

Answer (score 0):

Strength() returns a slice and error.
Try this.

```
strengths,err := f.Strength()
if err != nil{
   // Handler err
}

for _,x := range strengths{
  ...
}
```